# Android studio is not recognizing string or acceping it , just gives an error in gradle build everytime

Tags: java, android, string

[image]
[image]

My Android studio version is 3.2.0

Comment: Please don't post code screenshots, as they're hard to search. Instead, paste your code inside in the question. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`final` is a reserved keyword in Java, you cannot use it as a variable name. Use `finalString` or another descriptive name.

Answer (score 0):

The term `final` has some meaning in the programming language. These words are known as `KeyWords`. You cannot use keywords as `Identifiers` a.k.a variable names.

So, use any other name instead. As @MartinFink suggests, use

```
String finalString;
```

Hope this helps. Feel free to ask for clarifications...